# How to connect image regions

Tags: image-processing, julia, pca, mathematical-morphology

I've matrix with values, I've colored the matrix for visual analysis. The green region shows values e.g. 5 and brown shows values 6 and black shows value 0. I want to connect the broken region with value 5. I've tried different structuringElement.g. [110;110;000] and used 2 dilation followed by median filter to get this result.

```
  se_mask = centered(Bool[1 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 0 0])
    result = dilate(dilate(gt_mat, se_mask), se_mask)
    d_gt_mat = mapwindow(median, result, (5, 5))
```

I'm not sure whats a better way to connect the broken regions to fill up.
I'm working with JULIA.
[image: region 1]

[image: region 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in [ImageMorphology package](https://juliaimages.org/dev/examples/image_morphology/image_morphology/) might be what you are looking for.

For example, with the first image in the OP, something like this can be done:

```
using Images
using ImageMorphology
using ImageInTerminal
using IterTools

img = load("/path/to/dir/so-image.png")

gray_img = Gray.(img)

size(gray_img)    # (117, 238)

# applying dilate 7 times and then erode 7 times
closed_img = 
  nth(iterated(erode,nth(iterated(dilate, gray_img),7)),7)

save("/tmp/gray_img.png", gray_img)
save("/tmp/closed_img.png", closed_img)
```

and the results are:

[image: Original in gray version]
Original in gray version

[image: After processing]
After processing

Comment: What does expose `nth()`?

Comment: @Royi **IterTools** exports `nth`