# How to convert a Float64 Matrix into a RGB channel Matrix in Julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

Suppose I have the following Matrix:

```
img = [
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
]
```

I want to convert it to a Matrix in which each element represent the value as an RGB channel. I guess a somewhat translation should happen there. E.g., what is the equivalent RGB channel for representing `0.0`? You might say this can't happen or isn't possible. But I can convert the same Matrix into a black-and-white image:

```
julia> using Images
julia> Gray.(img)
```

And this shows an image as the output. So if it can translate the `0.0` into black and `1.0` into white by the Gray channel, Then I can expect existing the equivalent as an RGB channel.

**Q1:** What is my expected output?
**Ans:** A Matrix like this (here, with arbitrary numbers):

```
10×12 Array{RGB{Float64},2} with eltype RGB{Float64}:
 RGB{Float64}(0.412225,0.412225,0.412225)     …  RGB{Float64}(0.755344,0.755344,0.755344)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0368978,0.0368978,0.0368978)     RGB{Float64}(0.198098,0.198098,0.198098)
```

**Q2:** Why do I need this?
**Ans:** The whole idea is to be able to change the color of some pixels. So first, I have a Matrix with the `Float64` element type. Then I want to achieve the equivalent Matrix with the `RGB{Float64}` element type to change the value of some of them into something else (to show a pixel in a green color or anything.) and then see the picture to check the final image.

**Q3:** What I've tried?
**Ans:** I tried a straightforward approach, but I failed:

```
julia> RGB.(img)

julia> typeof(RGB.(img))
Matrix{RGB{N0f8}} (alias for Array{RGB{Normed{UInt8, 8}}, 2})
```

This command renders the image. It doesn't give me the expected Matrix. Then I tried this:

```
julia> channelview(RGB.(img))
3×10×12 reinterpret(reshape, N0f8, ::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}) with eltype N0f8:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
;;; …

[:, :, 12] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

But it's not what I expect.

Update:
Now tried another way:

```
julia> convert(Array{RGB, 2}, img)
# Just renders the result and doesn't show the matrix

julia> typeof(convert(Array{RGB, 2}, img))
Matrix{RGB} (alias for Array{RGB, 2})
```

Also, I tried `collect`ing it, but it led to the same result.

P.S. I need it to work in the **VScode**, not the REPL.

Comment: VSCODE does not do Julia, it executes JavaScript

Comment: @rioV8, the problem was with the VScode configuration, and the question is related to running the code in VSCode. So why did you remove the tag?

Comment: you don't run it in VSC but in a Notebook, VSC is just a "browser"/viewer for the Notebook server

Comment: @rioV8, What is your definition of a *Notebook*? Do you mean a Jupyter Notebook, for example?

Comment: VSC does not run any language you program, apart from the extensions you write, it interfaces to other programs via sockets or stdin/stdout to servers or terminal/shells. You run Julia in some kind of REPL that has the Julia extension interfaces to, is it the same REPL you launch from the command line, most likely not or at least it is configured differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by disabling the plot pane:
[image]

Comment: Issue solved. But any guess as to why? (and how to solve it without fiddling with menus and IDE)

Comment: @DanGetz, the "Plot Pane" was enabled. So it results in rendering the image each time I run `RGB.(img)` and omitting from giving the matrix. After disabling the "Plot Pane", it threw the matrix as the output rather than rendering the image.

Comment: I was wondering why it sometimes converted to `N0f8` and sometimes stayed `Float64`. On my REPL it stayed `Float64`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what you're seeing, realize that Julia calls `display(obj)` on the value `obj` returned from any command you execute. So when you do `RGB.(img)` (which is indeed the answer to your original question), that value gets returned---you could assign it to a variable and manipulate it.

But since you're working in VSCode, the default is to display anything that is a matrix of `Colorant` as an image, rather than a standard matrix. If you want to see it as a numeric matrix, you need to do a bit more work to specify that. Here's a demo in VSCode's Julia REPL:

[image: image display]

Just as you found, after the `imgrgb = RGB.(img)` line, the plot pane showed a representation of this image. But as the later lines show, you can still manipulate and display `imgrgb` as a regular matrix. The `MIME("text/plain")` forces it to display in text-mode rather than image-mode.

Answer (score -1):

Unable to understand why RGB.(img) is not the expected result? Looks fine to me.

| This command renders the image. It doesn't give me the expected Matrix.

```
julia> using Images
[ Info: Precompiling Images [916415d5-f1e6-5110-898d-aaa5f9f070e0]

julia> img = [
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
       ]
10×12 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5

julia> RGB.(img)
10×12 Array{RGB{Float64},2} with eltype RGB{Float64}:
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)  …  RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)  …  RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 RGB{Float64}(0.0,0.0,0.0)     RGB{Float64}(0.5,0.5,0.5)
```

Comment: I need it to work in the VScode, not the REPL.

Comment: I get the same result from running test script in VScode, can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ashwani-rathee/b64aed455f0fb73b671b97f2b0954c5e

Comment: Renders also just fine: https://i.imgur.com/oKBPPHe.png

Comment: I figured the issue was with the activated plot pane.