# How to clean nodes (corner points) from thinning result?

Tags: image-processing, julia

I'm working with Julia. I've the following result from a road's binary image
after Thinning (skeleton)
After thinning, I used Harris corner detection, which gets me red dots. To get line segments, I remove the red dots and each line is a line-segment with unique number.
The problem is that some red points are too close. How can I make red dots white (i.e. not corner points) if the points are too close?

```
using Images
using LinearAlgebra
t = thinning(road_image)
detection_method = harris
corners = imcorner(t, Percentile(99.5); method=detection_method)
labels = label_components(corners)
new_labels = label_components(labels) #because some labels are cluster of points, so this makes them 1
all_nodes = component_centroids(new_labels)
centre_line_node = CartesianIndex.(map(i -> trunc.(Int, all_nodes[i]), 1:length(all_nodes)))
img_labels = RGB{N0f8}.(t)
img_labels[centre_line_node] .= RGB(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Please add your raw image and full code (including package imports etc.) then we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is `thinning`? Still, you didn't provide the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't provide enough details about your code (even the full code) [**again**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595135/distance-between-contours-in-julia), I managed to get the job done using [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734306/11747148) using a little bit of justification:

```
using Images, ImageBinarization

road_image = load("oxLCJ.png") # The raw image

gimg = Gray.(road_image)
bin = binarize(gimg, UnimodalRosin()) .> 0.5
thinned = thinning(bin)

function check_adjacent(
  loc::CartesianIndex{2},
  all_locs::Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}
  )

  conditions = [
      loc - CartesianIndex(0,1) ∈ all_locs,
      loc + CartesianIndex(0,1) ∈ all_locs,
      loc - CartesianIndex(1,0) ∈ all_locs,
      loc + CartesianIndex(1,0) ∈ all_locs,
      loc - CartesianIndex(1,1) ∈ all_locs,
      loc + CartesianIndex(1,1) ∈ all_locs,
      loc - CartesianIndex(1,-1) ∈ all_locs,
      loc + CartesianIndex(1,-1) ∈ all_locs
  ]

  return sum(conditions)
end;

function find_the_contour_branches(img::BitMatrix)
  img_matrix = convert(Array{Float64}, img)
  not_black = findall(!=(0.0), img_matrix)
  contours_branches = Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}()
  for nb∈not_black
      t = check_adjacent(nb, not_black)
      (t==1 || t==3) && push!(contours_branches, nb)
  end
  return contours_branches
end;

function highlight_contours(img, contours; resize::Bool=false, scale::Union{Int64, Float64}=1)
  img_matrix = convert(Array{RGB, 2}, img)
  img_matrix[contours] .= RGB(1,0,0)

  if resize
      img_matrix = typeof(scale)==Int64 ? imresize(img_matrix, size(img).*scale) : imresize(img_matrix, ratio=scale)
  end
  return img_matrix
end;

contours = find_the_contour_branches(thinned)
highlight_contours(thinned, contours)
```

Gives me a result that if I zoom in, I see the following:
[image]

If you want details about the functions, see the previous answer I mentioned above (It's documented). Here, I just replaced `contours` with `contours_branches` and `t==1 && push!(contours, nb)` with `(t==1 || t==3) && push!(contours_branches, nb)` as far as I remember. But the idea is the same.

Update:
The code can get enhanced further. For example, I replaced the `for` loop in the `highlight_contours` function with `img_matrix[contours] .= RGB(1,0,0)`. But other improvements are out of the interest of this answer.

Comment: I can't using Imshow on it Here is the error imshow(highlight_contours(thinned, contours))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching sentinel_min(::Type{Union{AbstractFloat, FixedPoint}})
Closest candidates are:
  sentinel_min(::Type{T}) where T<:Union{Integer, FixedPoint} at /home/ /.julia/packages/Images/g4e1T/src/algorithms.jl:214
  sentinel_min(::Type{T}) where T<:AbstractFloat at /home/ /.julia/packages/Images/g4e1T/src/algorithms.jl:216
  sentinel_min(::Type{C}) where C<:AbstractRGB at /home/ /.julia/packages/Images/g4e1T/src/algorithms.jl:218
....

Comment: Also, for binarization, I get an error ERROR: UndefVarError: UnimodalRosin not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[47]:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ ~/.julia/packages/CUDA/DfvRa/src/initialization.jl:52

Comment: @h612, did you manage to get rid of those errors?

Comment: no, It didn't work. I'm using thinning for binarization for now.

Comment: @h612: let's continue here -> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250991/contours