# How to get connected components label in a binary image?

Tags: image-processing, julia, connected-components

I've a binary image where removing green dot gets me separate line segments. I've tried using label_components() function from Julia but it labels only verticall joined pixels as one label.
I'm using

```
using Images
img=load("current_img.jpg")
img[findall(img.==RGB(0.0,0.1,0.0))].=0 # this makes green pixels same as background, i.e. black
labels = label_components(img)
```

I'm expecteing all lines which are disjoint to be given a unique label
(as was a funciton in connected component labeling in matlab, but i can't find something similar in julia)

Comment: The reason `label_components` is not working for you, is because `img[findall(img.==RGB(0,1,0.0)]=0` does not change the green pixels into background pixels. Please check this, or rephrase the question to ask how to do that before asking about the components (after you are done with changing colors, `label_components(img, trues(3,3))` works well).

Comment: @DanGetz My previous comment was somehow deleted? Anyway, thanks , setting `trues(3,3)` fixed the issue.

Comment: Finally, some sort of engagement! In the future, it is important to make it easiest for the community to help you. Try to follow the guidelines and add code *someone else* can run easily. Help those who are willing to help! ESPECIALLY: The first line in your code, the brackets don't even match. It is more respectful to test the code you are writing for others.

Comment: @DanGetz: Dan, I'm extremely willing on answering these topics (It's so interesting for me). But I should feel this willing from the questionnaire side too! I'll post him a complete answer soon. Anyway, I don't know why my comment got removed. I'm sure that it was effective since they added the name of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you updated the question and added more details to make it clear, I decided to post the answer. Note that this answer utilizes some of the functions that I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734306/11747148); so, if you didn't find documentation for any of the following functions, I refer you to the previous answer. I operated on several examples and brought the results in the continue.
Let's begin with an image similar to the one you brought in the question and perform the entire operation from the scratch. for this, I drew the following:

[image]

I want to perform a segmentation process on it and labelize each segment and highlight the segments using the achieved labels.
Let's define the functions:

```
using Images
using ImageBinarization

function check_adjacent(
  loc::CartesianIndex{2},
  all_locs::Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}
  )

  conditions = [
    loc - CartesianIndex(0,1) ∈ all_locs,
    loc + CartesianIndex(0,1) ∈ all_locs,
    loc - CartesianIndex(1,0) ∈ all_locs,
    loc + CartesianIndex(1,0) ∈ all_locs,
    loc - CartesianIndex(1,1) ∈ all_locs,
    loc + CartesianIndex(1,1) ∈ all_locs,
    loc - CartesianIndex(1,-1) ∈ all_locs,
    loc + CartesianIndex(1,-1) ∈ all_locs
  ]

  return sum(conditions)
end;

function find_the_contour_branches(img::BitMatrix)
  img_matrix = convert(Array{Float64}, img)
  not_black = findall(!=(0.0), img_matrix)
  contours_branches = Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}()
  for nb∈not_black
    t = check_adjacent(nb, not_black)
    (t==1 || t==3) && push!(contours_branches, nb)
  end
  return contours_branches
end;

"""
  HighlightSegments(img::BitMatrix, labels::Matrix{Int64})

Highlight the segments of the image with random colors.

# Arguments
- `img::BitMatrix`: The image to be highlighted.
- `labels::Matrix{Int64}`: The labels of each segment.

# Returns
- `img_matrix::Matrix{RGB}`: A matrix of RGB values.
"""
function HighlightSegments(img::BitMatrix, labels::Matrix{Int64})
  colors = [
    # Create Random Colors for each label
    RGB(rand(), rand(), rand()) for label in 1:maximum(labels)
  ]

  img_matrix = convert(Matrix{RGB}, img)

  for seg∈1:maximum(labels)
    img_matrix[labels .== seg] .= colors[seg]
  end

  return img_matrix
end;

"""
  find_labels(img_path::String)

Assign a label for each segment.

# Arguments
- `img_path::String`: The path of the image.

# Returns
- `thinned::BitMatrix`: BitMatrix of the thinned image.
- `labels::Matrix{Int64}`: A matrix that contains the labels of each segment.
- `highlighted::Matrix{RGB}`: A matrix of RGB values.
"""
function find_labels(img_path::String)
  img::Matrix{RGB} = load(img_path)
  gimg = Gray.(img)
  bin::BitMatrix = binarize(gimg, UnimodalRosin()) .> 0.5
  thinned = thinning(bin)
  contours = find_the_contour_branches(thinned)
  thinned[contours] .= 0
  labels = label_components(thinned, trues(3,3))
  highlighted = HighlightSegments(thinned, labels)

  return thinned, labels, highlighted
end;
```

The main function in the above is `find_labels` which returns

1. The `thinned` matrix.
2. The `labels` of each segment.
3. The `highlighted` image (`Matrix`, actually).

First, I `load` the image, and `binarize` the `Gray` scaled image. Then, I perform the `thinning` operation on the binarized image. After that, I find the contours and the branches using the `find_the_contour_branches` function. Then, I turn the color of contours and branches to black in the thinned image; this gives me neat segments. After that, I labelize the segments using the `label_components` function. Finally, I highlight the segments using the `HighlightSegments` function for the sake of visualization (this is the bonus :)).
Let's try it on the image I drew above:

```
result = find_labels("nU3LE.png")

# you can get the labels Matrix using `result[2]`
# and the highlighted image using `result[3]`
# Also, it's possible to save the highlighted image using:
save("nU3LE_highlighted.png", result[3])
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

Also, I performed the same thing on another image:
[image]

```
julia> result = find_labels("circle.png")

julia> result[2]
14×16 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  1  1  0  0  0  3  3  0  0  0  5  5  5  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

As you can see, the labels are pretty clear. Now let's see the results of performing the procedure in some examples in one glance:

| Original Image | Labeled Image |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |