# How to connect lines using angle?

Tags: image-processing, julia, mathematical-morphology

Working in Julia, I've a set of lines on an image. Each line has a separate label assigned to it. The following image shows:

[image]

Note that these lines are not straight always, for instance:

[image]

I've used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045160/how-to-get-connected-components-label-in-a-binary-image). I'm working on the result of this statement `labels = label_components(thinned, trues(3,3))`. So I'm not sure how to get angle per label. I was thinking some PROTOTYPE like

```
for label in labels
 getangle_per_label(label)
end
then
interpolate labels with similar angles
```

I'm not sure how to implement it, any ideas?